# Override dispose method in a ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have the following model

```dart
class SelectorModel with ChangeNotifier {
    .... // stuff relating to the model
}
```

and inside my model I'm getting a stream of Firestore documents using the following:

```dart
_subscription = Firestore.instance   // _subscription is defined as an iVar above
      .collection('myCollection')
      .snapshots()
  .listen((querySnapshot)  {
    _jobs = querySnapshot.documents;
    callingMethod('');  // the method being called is inside of my model
  });
```

I need a way to dispose of the `_subsciption` so that when a change occurs in my Firestore database, it will not attempt to call `callingMethod()` when my model has already been disposed.

What I'm looking for is a method almost like the following for a ChangeNotifier:

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _subscription.cancel();
}
```

I looked through the provider [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/) but could not find anything.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't understand. Did you post the solution inside the question? That `dispose` example you gave is feasible and the correct solution.

Comment: @RémiRousselet, you are right, but for some reason I still get the error: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: A SelectJobModel was used after being disposed.
E/flutter ( 5628): Once you have called dispose() on a SelectJobModel, it can no longer be used.

Comment: That's a different issue. The `dispose` example you gave is right, then you need to fix that other bug

Comment: @RémiRousselet I have a question, I am closing my `_stremController` inside the overridden `dispose` function from the `ChangeNotifier`. Will it automatically close the `_streamController` or ? I am using `Provider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that if i understand you

```
_subscription = Firestore.instance   // _subscription is defined as an iVar above
      .collection('myCollection')
      .snapshots()
  .listen((querySnapshot)  {
    _jobs = querySnapshot.documents;
    callingMethod('');  // the method being called is inside of my model
   _subscription.cancel();
  });
```